# Laravel shows Symfony-styled exception even when APP_DEBUG set to false

Tags: laravel, debugging

Just deployed a new app to production and seeing a strange bug:

One of the pages has a PHP error and throws an exception. Strangely, it's a Symfony branded exception page ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl9bj.png)), different from the ones I've seen in Laravel before. Env file is already set to production environment and has APP_DEBUG=false.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've tried the following to clear & reset cache, but it didn't help

`php artisan config:cache`

Not sure if it matters, but the app was deployed using http://deployer.org with Deployer's Laravel recipe

Comment: Set env to production and see if it works

Comment: Here is an excerpt from my .env:
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false

Still the same issue

Comment: All migrations done? Seems like you weren't control every case (i.e. there is variable vs. there is not variable) in controller's method which loads that view file. Can you share that code?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the difference between having APP_DEBUG on or off is whether or not you see the stack trace and environment variables. If you want a custom 500 error page you should check [error handling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#http-exceptions).

Comment: Somehow the issue disappeared overnight. Woke up this morning and now seeing the standard '500 Server Error' page from Laravel without any additional changes to config files. Probably some sort of additional cache on my EC2 Instance.. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

The mostly likely reason for this is that when deployer runs `composer install`, it does so with the `--no-dev` option, which prevents the required packages from being installed. If you want to include dev packages upon deployment, add the following to deploy.php:

```
set('composer_options', '--verbose --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader');
```

This is the default `composer_options` value with `--no-dev` removed.

There are also slightly more complex options that include having different tasks for different hosts, which is detailed here: [PHPDeployer: set variable for local task based on host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561601/phpdeployer-set-variable-for-local-task-based-on-host)